# CI/CD with Terragrunt/Terraform mono-repo

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, cicd

I'm using Terragrunt within a mono-repo as below for multiple projects and environments:

```
projects/
├─ terragrunt.hcl
├─ teamA/
│  ├─ dev/
│  │  ├─ some-service/
│  │  │  ├─ terragrunt.hcl
│  ├─ prod/
│  │  ├─ some-service/
│  │  │  ├─ terragrunt.hcl
├─ teamB/
│  ├─ dev/
│  │  ├─ another-service/
│  │  │  ├─ terragrunt.hcl
│  ├─ prod/
│  │  ├─ another-service/
│  │  │  ├─ terragrunt.hcl
```

I've read that when using Terragrunt it's best practice to just run the `plan`/`apply` command on the module(s) that need to be deployed rather than `run-all apply` which will recursively run apply on all modules which can sometimes break things (?).

> I've also been informed if we run `apply` over everything, there are some resources that get rebuilt and could potentially wipe any manual changes teams have made. In a bit of a pickle.

However I'm not familiar with how to go about this in terms of a CI/CD pipeline and only executing commands on updated modules.

I would also assume then that dependencies need to be very explicitly stated in the `.hcl` files for each projects module so as to not try and deploy something that requires something else to already exist.

**Flow**

1. Engineer clones code
2. Engineer create and checkouts out new branch, eg. `fix/thing`
3. Engineer updates `projects/teamB/dev/another-service/terragrunt.hcl`
4. Engineer commits code and pushes back to remote along with branch
5. Engineer opens pull request

   - This triggers `terragrunt plan` on `projects/teamB/dev/another-service/terragrunt.hcl` some how
6. Engineer commits another change to `projects/teamA/prod/some-service/terragrunt.hcl`

   - this re-triggers a `plan` on only the affected modules

     - `projects/teamB/dev/another-service/terragrunt.hcl`
     - `projects/teamA/prod/some-service/terragrunt.hcl`
7. PR is approved and merged

   - this triggers an `apply` on only the affected modules:

     - `projects/teamB/dev/another-service/terragrunt.hcl`
     - `projects/teamA/prod/some-service/terragrunt.hcl`

Some answers I have seen involve adding instructions to the commit or PR for the CI/CD tool to parse. Another one mentioned running `git diff` and parsing the folders/files that have changed.

Has anyone deployed something similar with terragrunt or even terraform?

Comment: Why not just plan and apply everything? Terraform is meant to be idempotent (you can definitely do things that break this but it is discouraged) so it should be safe to do so and you just end up with a whole load of empty plans for the things that didn't change.

Comment: Ideally yes, but the people who have implemented this set up have done so in a way that the state drifts from what is actually deployed. Eg. The config for a resource is manually updated outside of TF so now if we rerun the IaC it wants to replace/destroy etc. I've found something called Atlantis https://www.runatlantis.io that seems to automate all this and target plan/apply on just modified modules.

Comment: @Ari were you able to solve this issue? I realized it's similar after I raised a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338828/run-terragrunt-apply-to-a-specific-codecommit-folder-using-codepipeline-and-code

Comment: Hey @BenL, I ended up putting together a pipeline shell script that runs a git diff between the main branch and incoming branch to figure out which "modules" were updated, then only run the plan command on those modules. Theoretically we could have just ran plan/apply on the entire repo as terra grunt was designed to do but the client had severely botched the implementation and doing so would break things in production. Take a look at https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/custom-workflows.html#use-cases its something I wanted to implement in stead of my hacky shell script.

Comment: The shell script approach makes sense as an 'automated' way to pick the folders to run terragrunt apply. I was also trying to think of a 'manual' way of doing it at the 'git push' level, and my only solution looks a bit like the atlantis approach, where we would define in the buildspec file what the terragrunt apply directories it would apply to. Downside of this approach is that people would need to keep remembering to update buildspec.yaml..