# CI/CD Deployment of the same Terraform Module for multiple Organizational Teams

Tags: terraform, gitlab, architecture, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am facing difficulties creating a proper setup for a CI/CD driven Terraform deployment strategy.

What I am looking for doesn't fit a classic "stages" approach and instead is more of a multiple production deployments of the same infrastructure components for different teams (organizational).

For example.. In my typical Software Engineering projects, the team has a CI/CD Pipeline where infrastructure is, depending on stage / job, deployed to the equivalent infrastructure stage for their software. They know how to do stuff and are YBI/YRI enabled.

In the Platform I have modules, again two stages (test and production) and a Repository glueing it together. Deployed via CI/CD. All good so far.

Now I have a project at hand where a lot of teams will require the same piece of infrastructure (a finished TF module) but do not use GIT / CI/CD / any modern method / automation. Training them is out of scope. Actually they are required to just "get the infrastructure" to use it by the organization.

On the other hand, I still want to be able to maintain the deployed infrastructure instead of "fire and forget". Therefor me and my team will provision, hand over and maintain the infrastructure. They are free to use it within the provided settings.

Requirements I want to achieve:

- One GIT Repository with all the deployments inside (keeping the "Organizational Project" together)
- One state file per deployment ("Organizational Team")
- CI/CD deploys added Terraform configurations automatically on main merge
- CI/CD dosen't update already existing Terraform configurations when new ones are added (it should however be possible by my team. Non CI/CD in this case is viable)
- CI/CD configuration should not be required to be extended for new Terraform configurations
- It shouldn't require complex bash / sh magic

F.e.

```
./team1/main.tf
./team2/main.tf
./.../main.tf
```

The folders have a `main.tf` using the module with team variable values and a `providers.tf` with provider setup for the team (Azure Subscription).

Now that seems simple and where is the question. I want this to be executed with CI/CD. Colleagues should be able to create a MR with a new folder + terraform configuration and get the infrastructure that we can maintain from there but also hand it over to be used.

I haven't found anything really helpful while a lot of inputs are close.

I am pretty sure I am missing something very easy and just fail to google / ChatGPT the problem correctly.

Using GitLab-CI + Azure btw.

Thanks for your inputs.

Closest finding is [CI/CD with Terragrunt/Terraform mono-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556638/ci-cd-with-terragrunt-terraform-mono-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following outline should accomplish what you want. This assumes you're using [gitlab-managed terraform state](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.html), otherwise you'll need to adapt the solution for whatever system you use to manage your remote state.

Assume you have a structure like so:

```
.
├── projects
│   ├── team1
│   │   └── main.tf
│   ├── team2
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── team3
│       └── main.tf
└── tf-autodeploy
```

This shell script `tf-autodeploy` (described below) accepts one argument, which is the root directory containing subdirectories for each independent set of tf definitions (`projects` in the above structure). It will traverse each directory, check if terraform state already exists; if it does *not* exist, it will terraform apply will be run.

Then you can have your ci configuration that (in relevant part) defines two jobs: one to apply automatic updates for *new* infrastructure deployments (not changes to existing state) and a job that can be run manually and specifying a variable of which project to update.

```yaml
auto_tf_apply:
  # automatically deploy _new_ infrastructure only once merged to default branch
  needs: [init, validate]
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes: projects/**/*
  script:
    - tf-autoupdate "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/projects"


tf_apply_manual:
  when: manual
  needs: [init, validate, plan]
  variables:
    PROJECT:
      description: "The project to deploy changes to (e.g., 'team1')"
    TF_ROOT: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/projects/$PROJECT"
    TF_STATE_NAME: "$PROJECT"
  script:
    - if [[ "$PROJECT" == "" ]]; then exit 1; fi
    - cd $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform apply
```

The `tf-autoupdate` script run in the `auto_tf_apply` job satisfies the requirements of "CI/CD deploys added Terraform configurations automatically on main merge" and "dosen't update already existing Terraform configurations"

The `tf_apply_manual` job allows you to manually update existing configurations by running the manual job and [specifying the variable value](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs) for the specific project (e.g., `team1`) to be updated.

For additional context, see the examples in [the gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/iac/mr_integration.html#example-gitlab-ciyml-file).

---

The contents of an example the `tf-autodeploy` script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# tf-autodeploy
root=$1
for project_name in "$root"/*; do
    pushd "${root}/${project_name}"
    export TF_STATE_NAME="${project_name}"
    export TF_ROOT="${root}/${project_name}"
    # check if state already exists
    if ! gitlab-terraform state list
    then
        echo "creating new deployment for ${project_name}"
        gitlab-terraform apply
    else
        echo "state already exists, skipping ${project_name}"
    fi
    popd
done
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the in depth answer. This should be able to do exactly what I need with some tweeks here and there.